# 2 rows in the same line if there is enough space

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

If you have something like this:

```
Wrap(
Row(
  Box(75),
  Box(75),
  Box(75),
),
Row(
  Box(75),
  Box(75),
  Box(75),
),
)
```

The second row is placed in separate line after first row even if there is enough space. Is there a way for me to place them side by side in 1 line, and they only go to 2 lines when the rows get too big for the screen size?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rows are broken to different line because by default the occupy maximum width. To achieve the desired layout, set Row's width to `MainAxisSize.min`